# Nginx location, alias, rewrite, root

Tags: deployment, static, nginx, url-rewriting, location

I'm serving /foo/bar/ by way of proxypass and want to continue doing so.  However, I would like to serve /foo/bar/baz.swf statically from say /var/www/mystatic/baz.swf and so forth.

I was hoping that I could do something like

```
    location /foo/bar/(.*) {
      alias /var/www/mystatic/;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass ....;
      ... 
    }
```

And /foo/bar/ would go to the application server while /foo/bar/(.*) would be served statically.

the docs say that I can't do this and need to use a combination of root and rewrite: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule

Adding to the complication, I would like to continue using the ancient, unsupported 0.5.33.  Any help would b greatly appreciated.

Edit: moving forward, someone suggested using root instead of alias.  But, it doesn't seem that I can use any regex on the location directive  with my version?  Here, /foo/bar/baz.swf is served by the proxy_pass!  I have the file at /var/www/foo/bar/baz.swf.

```
    location /foo/bar/(.+) {
      root /var/www/;
    }
```

Comment: lol, worst question on SO badge.

Comment: Why don't you just put `location /foo/bar/(.+)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this; but it's slightly esoteric.  Try using:

```
location ^~ /foo/bar {
    alias /var/www/mystatic/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass ....;
}
```

These options are documented on the Wiki http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#location

Comment: If I do that /foo/bar/ is served by nginx .. if I add the trailing slash ... I still don't correctly line up /foo/bar/baz.js

Answer (score 1):

```
location = /foo/bar/baz.swf {}
```

will clear clear any options set to /foo/bar/baz.swf.  So you can leave it 
where it is as the proxy options will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
# mkdir /var/www/foo  
# mv /var/www/mystatic /var/www/foo/bar
```

then use this config:

```
location ~ ^/foo/bar/(.+) {
  root /var/www/;
}
```