# How can I make nginx rewrite play nice with alias?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, alias

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10699755/344286), I'm having an issue with nginx rewrites not playing nicely.

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {                                                                           
    listen 80;                                                                     
    server_name myserver.com www.myserver.com;                               
    index index.html;                                                              
    root /var/www/myserver.com/site/;                                           

    location /blog {                                                               
        alias /var/www/myserver.com/blog/output/;                               
        break;                                                                     
    }                                                                              

    location / {                                                                   
        autoindex on;                                                              
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;                                             
    }                                                                              

    location /.hg {                                                                
        deny all;                                                                  
        return 404;                                                                
    }                                                                              

    location ~ \.html$ {                                                           
        try_files $uri =404;                                                       
    }                                                                              

    location @htmlext {                                                            
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;                                               
    }                                                                              

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;                                    
}
```

It looks like the issue is with the `location ~ \.html` rule. When I remove that, it works fine.

I've tried multiple things such as:

- Moving the `location /blog` directive up to the top (it used to be at the bottom)
- Putting `break;` in as the linked question suggests.

So far, nothing seems to work. In the current configuration I get a 404, which is what shows up in the `access.log` as well.

How can I make the rewrite work to hide the `.html` extensions, but also let me serve up the `blog/output/` content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possibly the weirdest answer to this question comes verbatim from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823259/344286):

```
location ^~ /blog {
        alias /var/www/myserver.com/blog/output/;                               
        break;
}
```

Honestly, even after reading the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) I still can't explain why this works. I know it has something to do with the regex matching behavior of `^~` but that's all I've got.